# Pulling out constants out conditional expectation

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation, martingale

Given
$p_t = p_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ and $\varepsilon ~ $i.i.d. with$~E(\varepsilon_t) = 0~\forall~t$

I wanna derive the conditional expectation for $p_t$ and I know it is $p_{t-1}$ since it is a martingale.

My attempt:
$E(p_t|p_{t-1}) = E(p_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t|p_{t-1}) = p_{t-1} + E(\varepsilon_t)$ = $p_{t-1}$ 
Another idea would be:
$E(p_t|p_{t-1}) = E(p_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t|p_{t-1}) = E(p_{t-1}|p_{t-1}) + E(\varepsilon_t|p_{t-1})$ = $p_{t-1}$ but $p_{t-1}$ is no random variable so I don't think that the second way makes too much sense either.

I am unsure if it is valid to pull out $p_{t-1}$ out of the conditional expectation and if it is, what's the rule behind it?

Comment: You can pull given random vars out of the expectation as if they’re constant.

Comment: And what is the correct mathematical notation then ?

Comment: The second one reflects the steps better, but the flrst one is also not wrong.